# minimum steps to reduce n to 1 (variant)

Tags: dynamic-programming

Given a number X, you are allowed to perform one of these operations:

1-Decrement X by 1.

2-Increment X by 1.

3-If X is a multiple of 3 you can divide X by 3.

I think there's a O(n) dp solution for the problem , but how to solve it for 1 <= x <=10^9 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in O(2log_3N) time (if N~3^n, it takes ~2n goes), as every move is:

- n mod 3 == 0 : divide by 3
- n mod 3 == 1 : subtract 1
- n mod 3 == 2 : add 1

so we need at most 2 moves to reduce by a factor of 3, which we need to do ~n times.

```html
<input type='number' id='nm'/>
<button onclick='go();'>Go</button>
<br>
<span id='out'/>
<script>

function go() {
var n=nm.value;
var nc=0;
out.textContent=n;
while (n>1) {
  n3=n%3;
    switch (n3) {
      case 0: {n/=3;break;}
      case 1: {n--;break;}
      case 2: {n++;break;}
    }
  nc++;
  out.textContent+=','+ n;
  }
out.textContent+=' ::'+ nc;
}

</script>
```

Comment: this needs a tweak if n==2, like `if(n==2) {n--;nc++;
  out.textContent+=','+ n;break;}` immediately after the`while` statement

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but could you explain to me why this algorithm  will always give optimal solution ?

Comment: it is greedy in that it goes for the closest multiple of 3. If you are at say 3x+1 and 3^ky-2, it gives the same number of basic operations: my code goes to 3x, then to x. But even if it was to add twice to get to 3^ky, and then k divisions to get to y (k+2 moves), x happens to equal 3^{k-1}y-1 (3x=3^ky-3, add +1 to both sides) and so also k+2 moves. Similarly for sandwiched between 3x-1 and 3^k+2. If you hit n=2, go straight to 1, not 2->3->1.